# Deploying GWT app to tomcat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat, deployment

I want to use tomcat server in development mode with GWT. When I use embedded Jetty it deploys application to the current directory(where my war folder is located). So it generates all the files there. How can I configure eclipse to use tomcat server and all the deployment stuff to be copied to tomcat webapps directory. I have tried to use `-noserver` option in Run conigurations, but it doesn't copy any resource from war directory to server deployment directory.
Can I use tomcat server in such manner?
P.S. i want to solve this problem withou ant or maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using my own server in development mode instead of GWT's built-in Jetty instance](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s)

You will need to copy the contents of the WAR folder over, but only once.

Comment: You don't have to copy anything actually, you can configure Tomcat to load your webapp directly from your war folder (I don't know how, but it's possible; FYI I do this with an external Jetty server).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Eclipse WTP? It allows deploying to a server right from within Eclipse.

For a GWT project, you'd then, in addition, follow that recipe: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee

Comment: I have read this item, but when deploying it doesn't copy content of war folder to server. Actually it creates WEB-INF folder on server and gwt public folder, but doesn't copy html and css files

Comment: Probably your war folder isn't set as a "content directory" in your project, so WTP doesn't deploy it. I don't know WTP much (only used it for a few weeks) but check the "deployment assembly" page in your project's properties; you war folder should be deployed to "/".

Comment: yes, war folder is deployed to "/", but it takes no effect in deplyment time